# covariance matrix gsl

Tags: c, statistics, gsl

I am trying to calculate the Mahalanobis distance between two vectors a and b. Eventually, I will be using this as a distance measure in statistical algorithms. I am using gsl to implement them. The formula for the mahalanobis distance is sqrt((a-b)'c^-1(a-b)), where c is the covariance matrix. According to [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Covariance.html) gsl documentation, it takes in two data sets and returns one covariance value. I am not sure how to calculate the covariance matrix using that. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to understand the calcuation of a covariance matrix first, second heres a sample code to get you started

```
for (i = 0; i < A->size1; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < A->size2; j++) {
          a = gsl_matrix_column (A, i);
          b = gsl_matrix_column (A, j);
          double cov = gsl_stats_covariance(a.vector.data, a.vector.stride,b.vector.data, b.vector.stride, a.vector.size);
          gsl_matrix_set (C, i, j, cov);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. In this code snippet is A the data matrix? Because in my case, all I have when the function is called are two vectors of the same size. So, I'm still not sure how to get the covariance matrix between two vectors. Because if I call gsl_stats_covariance between a and b all I get is a single value.

Comment: yup `A` is a matrix, and `a` and `b` are columns of the matrix `A` The resulting matrix `C` is your covariance matrix.....

Comment: shouldn’t it be `A->size2` twice? size1 is the number of rows, and you don’t loop over rows. also i doesn’t change, so why don’t you assign a in the outer loop?